# RegEx for capturing a specific alphanumeric pattern in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I want this code to return the Socket model. Instead of *AM3+* returns *6300*.

```
$string = "AMD FX X6 Six Core 6300, AM3+, 8MB L3 (BOX)Serie : FX,Socket : AM3+,Numar nuclee : 6,Frecventa : 3500 MHz,Frecventa Turbo : 4100 MHz";

preg_match('/[Socket]+[ : |:]+(?<socket>([A-Z]{2}+[0-9]{1}+[+]|[A-Z]{2}+[0-9]{1}|[A-Z]{3}+[ ]+[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}))/', $string, $array);

echo $array['socket'];
```

Comment: Try it on https://regex101.com/

Comment: Um...  `[Socket]+` matches one or more of *any* letter in `Socket`. Read the regex documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we would be simply capturing Socket, followed by whitespace, `:` and we would be capturing what would be before the first comma after that, which is our desired output `(.+?)`:

```
((Socket)\s+?:\s+?(.+?)),
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/((Socket)\s+?:\s+?(.+?)),/m';
$str = '$string = "AMD FX X6 Six Core 6300, AM3+, 8MB L3 (BOX)Serie : FX,Socket : AM3+,Numar nuclee : 6,Frecventa : 3500 MHz,Frecventa Turbo : 4100 MHz";
';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "Socket : AM3+,"
    [1]=>
    int(65)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "Socket : AM3+"
    [1]=>
    int(65)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Socket"
    [1]=>
    int(65)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "AM3+"
    [1]=>
    int(74)
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to get "AM3+", the processor socket.  I want to match exactly this: Socket : AM3+ ("Socket" exact word, " : " and AM3+ as two letters, one number and a plus + ). Thank you!